# ListViewBinding images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have image in my ListView handler i would like to add path to images with code like i did with my TextBlock.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ListMenuItems" SelectionChanged="ListMenuItems_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Name="yourMom" Source="{Binding myI_Uri}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Width="60" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"   Text="{Binding}" Margin="10"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="Gray" Width="500" Height="0.5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And this is my code in program:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DrawerLayout.InitializeDrawerLayout(); //Intialize drawer 
        string[] menuItems = new string[5] { "My Notes", "Favorite 2", "Favorite 3", "Favorite 4", "Favorite 5" };
        ListMenuItems.ItemsSource = menuItems.ToList();  //Set Menu list
        string[] PICTURE_PATH = new string[5] { "/slikeProgrami/Menu1.png", "/slikeProgrami/ozadje1.jpg", "/slikeProgrami/Menu1.png", "/slikeProgrami/ozadje1.jpg", "/slikeProgrami/Menu1.png" };
        ListMenuItems.ItemsSource = PICTURE_PATH.ToList();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the Image Source property to that string you're already binding to TextBlock.Text:

```
<Image Source="{Binding }" />
```